# C# Random Always Same Number

Tags: c#, android, mono

```
public class ExpAdapter : BaseExpandableListAdapter
{
  private int seed = 1000;

  public override View GetChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, bool isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        if (convertView == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
            convertView = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.inspection_row_2, null);
        }

        int currentID;
        Random randomizer = new Random(seed);

        TextView question = (TextView) convertView.FindViewById(Resource.Id.questionText);
        RadioGroup radio = (RadioGroup) convertView.FindViewWithTag("actionGroup");
        currentID = randomizer.Next(1,101);
        radio.Id = currentID;
        RadioButton pass = (RadioButton) convertView.FindViewWithTag("passed");
        currentID = randomizer.Next(1,101);
        pass.Id = currentID;
        RadioButton fail = (RadioButton) convertView.FindViewWithTag("failed");
        currentID = randomizer.Next(1,101);
        fail.Id = currentID;
        RadioButton correct = (RadioButton)convertView.FindViewWithTag("corrected");
        currentID = randomizer.Next(1,101);
        correct.Id = currentID;
        RadioButton na = (RadioButton)convertView.FindViewWithTag("na");
        currentID = randomizer.Next(1,101);
        na.Id = currentID;

        string[][] items = questions.childItems();
        question.Text = items[groupPosition][childPosition];

        seed++;

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Using a breakpoint to step through the above, currentID = 1 throughout execution.  The above method gets called repeatedly as MonoDroid creates the child group of controls under the parent group and currentID is ALWAYS = 1.  I have also tried creating currentID and randomizer as private static variables within the entire class.  Same result.

EDIT:  I attempted to create the new Random instances with a seed value that differed for each call to GetChildView.  Code is edited above to show how I did that.  Still the value of currentID is always = 1.  Below is screen shot of information for randomizer in Locals.  This information looks the same regardless of what the seed number is. ???

[image]

Comment: Have you tried feeding seed to randomizer ?

Comment: Yes.  Same result.  Also, it is my understanding that using seed in my example would generate the same numbers during each iteration.  The number is being used for the object's ID and needs to be unique.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking me.  I expect it to create a new Random object using DateTime and then grab the Next random number 5 times before the next iteration of GetChildView at which point a new Random object is created based on that current DateTime.

Comment: @jmease have you seen this `@DmitriyReznik`.

Comment: @jmease - Read up on how the Random class works, your using it wrong, you need to either seed it with a value that is guaranteed to change everytime the event happens or intialize it once and seed it once, and simple call the next random number, when the event happens.

Comment: Like I said, I tried creating the Random object just once as a private static variable in the constructor of my class with a seed value. The class is only being instantiated once.  But currentID remained 1 throughout each call to the Next method on that object. That is when I changed it over to creating a new Random object within the GetChildView method itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Randomizer is calculated with system time in milliseconds. So, if you call it rapidly, ie in same millisecond, they get seeded with same number, thus resulting in same random number.

Comment: Yes, but I am creating only one Random object and calling the Next method on it 5 times before creating a new one.  Wouldn't at least the value of that single object change with each call to Next even if the next new Random object gets created in the same millisecond?

Comment: @jmease The code works fine on .NET 4.0, seeded with the default time based seed, or otherwise.  It seems like a platform specific issue.

Comment: @RichardHein, I fear you might be correct.  MonoDroid has been a little buggy so far. I've decided just to use the incremented seed variable to assign unique IDs instead of using the Random class.  Seems to serve the purpose.